# Can't move between independent area paths Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-boards

**Host Details:**

OS Editon: Azure Devops server 2016

OS Build: 1607

**Azure DevOps Details:**

AZ server: 2019

**The issue:**

For one Team Project, we are requiring to have three different sub-area paths so we can place work there and Properly follow it.

**The config:**

Actually this configuration was able to been place in one oportunity, see bellow reference:

[image: sub-areas]

Because this approach introduce multiples advantages was decided to replicate it but, and here is when the issue starts not able to replicate with exact same parameters or via multiple attemp combinations, also tested under other landscapes with the same OS and AZ server,

which could be the issue? if before was possible as the screenshots proof it?

**A Glimpse of other Attemp config:**

[image: sub-tasks config]

[image: sub-tasks board view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved by myself**

Hello Kevin, thanks for reaching me out so swiftly,

I did found the issue, due to a lack in Azure DevOps documentation didn't know that when creating a new Team Project have to create the extra teams within the Project before anything else, and then is that can proceed to add define the sub-area paths in the Boards Section and then is when is possible to have First multiple teams within a team project and Second have enabled the Work Items Button for each team sprint:

[image]

See for example this MS official documentation how they don't make any clarification of it: {{ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=azure-devops }} :

[image]

Also here {{ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser }} :

[image]
enter image description here

So MS docs miss that point completaly!

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you only have a single team (Dev Team).  The Sprints page is generated according to teams. You need to assign the sub-areas to different teams, then it will show other Sprints page.

You could refer to the following steps to configure the team.

1. Create new teams (e.g. Team A and Team B) in `Project Settings -> Teams`.

[image]

2. Navigate to `Project Settings -> Team configuration`. Select the Team and configure the Area and Iteration Path.

[image]

```
Team A  Area : Team A Iteration : Team A
Team C  Area : Team C Iteration : Team C
```

Here are the docs about configure [Area Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) and [Iteration Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

**Note:** Area Path and Iteration Path are required.

Then the created sub-areas will exist in the Sprints dropdown list.

[image]

**Update:**

You could refer to this doc: [Manage and configure team tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/manage-teams?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)

The Boards directory  list in `Boards -> Boards` and the sprint directory list are synchronized.

This document states that the drop-down list is a team selector.

[image]

You can also check the items contained in the team.